# Changing RabbitMQ Consumer Weights

Tags: java, rabbitmq, load-balancing

As far as I see on the **rabbitmq** documentation, the enqueued messages are dispatched in a *round robin* fashion to the connected consumers. However, I want one of my consumers to take just, let' s say 1% of the messages for *pilot testing* purposes.

Is it possible to achieve that? Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a second queue, bind to the same exchanges and deploy your testing purpose consumer to consume from there? That way you won't influence your business as usual consumers and you can test as much as you want on the second queue.

Comment: @JohanP Unfortunately the rabbitmq server I mentioned here doesn' t belong to us. It is a remote queue and managed by some other company. We are just expected to prepare the consumer side.

Comment: I guess what you can do is set a prefetch of 10 e.g. on one consumer and prefetch of 1 on your testing consumer. Maybe put the testing consumer to sleep for x amount, that way it will definitely consume less than the other one(s).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [consumer priorities](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html).

RabbitMQ will be sending the messages to high priority consumers more often than the low priority consumers. The only time it will go to the low priority consumer is when the high priority consumer is blocked. A consumer becomes blocked when it has reached the max number of unacknowledged messages. This can be set by playing with [`basic.qos`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) for the consumer.

Priority for consumers can be set by the following:

> Set the `x-priority` argument in the `basic.consume` method to an integer value. Consumers which do not specify a value have priority 0. Larger numbers indicate higher priority, and both positive and negative numbers can be used.

So, you can define the priority for your test consumer and other consumers.
Here is the sample provided by RabbitMQ documentation.

```
Channel channel = ...;
Consumer consumer = ...;
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-priority", 10);
channel.basicConsume("my-queue", false, args, consumer);
```

If you strictly want to control the distribution of the messages across the clients, you might need to write a custom plugin to modify the behavior of [consumers](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/src/rabbit_queue_consumers.erl#L440).

Comment: So there is no way to achieve what I want, right? I have seen the x-priority setting but it doesn' t change the way rabbitmq distributes the queued messages unless higher priority consumers work as expected.

Comment: Only way that comes to my mind is to write a custom plugin. But that's not an option for you as the server doesn't belong to you.

Comment: I would slow down my consumer with small prefetch and sleep calls as mentioned by JohanP